# ".NetPortable version v4.5 profile259" using Visua Studio 2017 enterprise

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

While am installing a plugin to projects the given below error is occured to solve this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'linqtotwitter 4.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0

Comment: The last version that explicitly states that it still supports PCL projects is 3.1.2.  Looks like version 4.x is moving to .NET Standard, it is the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `linqtotwitter` pre-release version of 4.2.0-beta2 as it properly supports that profile.

```
<package id="linqtotwitter" version="4.2.0-beta2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
```

**Note:** You can check the package dependancies on Nuget.org site by opening the packages `Dependencies` section.

For linqtotwitter version= 4.2.0-beta2 you can see the section (Portable Class Library (.NETFramework 4.5, Windows 8.0, WindowsPhoneApp 8.1)) that covers the Profile258 project that you are trying to install it into:

```
 Dependencies

.NETFramework 4.5

Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)
.NETStandard 0.0

System.Reactive (>= 3.1.1)
System.Reactive.Core (>= 3.1.1)
System.Reactive.Interfaces (>= 3.1.1)
System.Reactive.Linq (>= 3.1.1)
System.Reactive.PlatformServices (>= 3.1.1)
MonoAndroid 0.0

Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.21)
Microsoft.Bcl.Compression (>= 3.9.85)
Microsoft.Net.Http (>= 2.2.29)
modernhttpclient (>= 2.4.2)
Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)
MonoTouch 0.0

Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.21)
Microsoft.Bcl.Compression (>= 3.9.85)
Microsoft.Net.Http (>= 2.2.29)
modernhttpclient (>= 2.4.2)
Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)

Portable Class Library (.NETFramework 4.5, Windows 8.0, WindowsPhoneApp 8.1)

Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.21)
Microsoft.Bcl.Compression (>= 3.9.85)
Microsoft.Net.Http (>= 2.2.29)
modernhttpclient (>= 2.4.2)
Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)
UAP 10.0

Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)
Xamarin.iOS 0.0

Microsoft.Bcl (>= 1.1.10)
Microsoft.Bcl.Build (>= 1.0.21)
Microsoft.Bcl.Compression (>= 3.9.85)
Microsoft.Net.Http (>= 2.2.29)
modernhttpclient (>= 2.4.2)
Rx-Core (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Interfaces (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Linq (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-Main (>= 2.2.5)
Rx-PlatformServices (>= 2.2.5)
```